# can kendo editor drag resize handle be made to work like the one here on SO

Tags: kendo-ui, editor

Can the drag handle of the kendo Editor be made to work like the one here on SO, with a thicker bottom border and the handle location center-south?

The kendo-editor has a thick top-border and a thin bottom border. If that could be reversed, it would be just a little more user friendly, as positioning the mouse pointer on the bottom border would be a tad easier.

Comment: Do you met with k-resize-handle of last column right side getting moved along with normal columns, i need that fixed and data 'll be scroll up and have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS as a starting point and adjust it to your preferences:

```
  .k-editor div.k-resize-handle {
    padding: 0;
    left: 50%; /* or 0 for full width */
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px; /* or 100%  */
    margin-left: -25px; /* or 0 */
    height: 10px;
    cursor: s-resize;
  }

  .k-editor div.k-resize-handle .k-icon {
    display: none;
  }
```